# Why does VirtualBox not detect my Android device?

Tags: android, windows, usb, virtualbox

Using VirtualBox 4.2.12, I've set up a Lubuntu 13.04 VM on a Windows 7 host. I specified a USB filter for my Galaxy S, but neither the VM nor VirtualBox detects it.

After searching the internet, I found `vboxmanage list usbhost`, which does not show my device connected. However, `adb devices` *does* list the device, and I can see it in Device Manager. All drivers on the host are up to date.

It seems to me that if I can get VirtualBox to recognize the device, I shouldn't have a problem getting the VM to. So, how come VirtualBox doesn't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it working. There were a couple of things that I learned that might be helpful. First of all, I was following [this guide](http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/use-android-devices-for-guest-ubuntu-os-in-virtualbox-on-windows-7-host/).

VirtualBox currently has problems with USB 3 ports. Check that your device is plugged into a USB 2 port. After I did that, my device was able to be detected by `vboxmanage list usbhost` on my Windows host.

Unfortunately, this didn't completely solve my issue. VirtualBox would list the phone under the Devices menu, and I could select it, but Lubuntu gave me no indication that a device was connected. In fact, `lsusb` and `adb devices` both came up empty. I ran `dmesg` and found this error message:

```
[ 846.648000] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 1
[ 846.675000] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 846.884000] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
```

I found the following [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797789) and set this variable, which solved my problem.

```
echo Y | sudo tee /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/old_scheme_first
```

**EDIT** I discovered that the problem came up again during restart. After a LOT of trial and error, I found that each time I start up, I have to connect the Android device, then set the `old_scheme_first` variable, then disconnect and reconnect the device before the VM would recognize it. It's an annoying process, so if anyone has any insight, I'd appreciate it. On the other hand, it's a VM, so I won't have to restart it often =)

Comment: The link to the guide is now private :(

Comment: @Phantomazi Sorry, this has been so long ago now that I don't remember what I did. It looks like you might be able to create a good portion of it from my answer and some experimentation. If you get it working, other people might find it beneficial if you post a more thorough solution here.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150307161334/https://binglongx.com/2013/03/05/use-android-devices-for-guest-ubuntu-os-in-virtualbox-on-windows-7-host/

Answer (score 8):

You have to manually add host user to Virtual Box users list, try this on your **host machine**:

```
sudo usermod -G vboxusers -a $USER
```

**log off** and **log in** again see if devices are listing.

Comment: This is the only valid answer. Can test with `vboxmanage list usbhost` as logged in user but super user should be able to see the attached usb devices.

Comment: Once you install the extension pack your user needs to be removed from the `vboxusers` group or again you won't see any host connected usb.

Answer (score 3):

After, you set filter and lunched VM. have you tried physically re-attach the device?

Comment: Yes, and I get the same results. `adb devices` on the host shows the device, but `vboxmanage` does not and `adb devices` on the VM does not. VirtualBox doesn't seem to detect the device.

Comment: After i've created the filter, i've restarted guest then I've reatached the android device, and it worked.